# How to loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a couple of jQuery function with a similar syntax.

```
$("#item-1").hover(function(){
    $(".item-1").animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $(".item-1").animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});

$("#item-2").hover(function(){
    $(".item-2").animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $(".item-2").animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});

$("#item-3").hover(function(){
    $(".item-3").animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $(".item-3").animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});
```

My question is how to shorten my code with the help of a loop.
I tried the following but that didn’t work:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {

  $("#item-" + i).hover(function(){
    $(".item-" + i).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
  },function(){
    $(".item-" + i).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
  });

}
```

Comment: Your loop should work properly...

Comment: Maybe you could show the HTML ?

Comment: Not like this. Besides the approach, his mistake is using a class selector inside.

Comment: ID and class names are correct as I don’t want to animate the element I hover but another one with the corresponding class name (it’s coincidence that they both have the same name, although maybe a bit misleading in my example …)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
  (function(index){
    $("#item-" + index).hover(function(){
      $(".item-" + index).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
    },function(){
      $(".item-" + index).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
    });
  })(i);
}
```

The problem with your loop is that the variable i is not captured by the hover function. With this, the i variable will be captured properly.

Answer (score 5):

You could  you jQuery's `attributeStartsWith` selector

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a
>   value beginning exactly with a given string.

The following will work if you have .item-x classes elements:

```
$('[id^="item-"]').hover(function(){
    $("."+this.id).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $("."+this.id).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});
```

Otherwise in my suggestion you could do it by :

```
$('[id^="item-"]').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});
```

Comment: Fix the selector to "#"+this.id and I will give you that upvote. :D

Comment: But I've done according to his question otherwise I could do it  $(this).animate....

Comment: I know, but his question is flawed :)

Comment: Oh, if it should trigger another element, than I get it, he is right.

Answer (score 3):

Put a universal class `item` to all elements and then just call the function for all items:

```
$(".item").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});
```

Comment: I am not saying its wrong but what if there is no need of class easy solution is to use multiple selector ...

Comment: Sure, but it's always a good practice to group your stuff with similar properties.

Answer (score 3):

try out might work for you

```
$("#item-1, #item-2, #item-3").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add a class to your item, to select them, and do this

```
$(".item").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:1},"slow");
  },function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:0},"slow");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your html is similar to below,

```
<div class="item-class" id="item-1">
    <div class="item-sub-class"></div>
</div>
<div class="item-class" id="item-2">
    <div class="item-sub-class"></div>
</div>
<div class="item-class" id="item-3">
    <div class="item-sub-class"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of id use class

```
$(".item-class").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.item-sub-class').animate({opacity:1},"slow");
},function(){
    $(this).find('.item-sub-class').animate({opacity:0},"slow");
});
```